# How to send mail from a Windows batch file using Blat utility

Tags: windows, email, batch-file, smtp

I want to send a mail from a Windows batch file.
Here is my code:

```
blat test.log -server smtp.gmx.com -to dest@gmail.com -f address@gmail.com -s "test mail" -u "address@gmail.com" -pw "password" -debug -log envois-mails.log -timestamp
```

Here is the error I get:

```
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): <<<getline<<< 535 Authentication credentials invalid
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): The SMTP server did not accept Auth PLAIN value.
Are your login userid and password correct?
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): >>>putline>>> AUTH LOGIN
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): <<<getline<<< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): >>>putline>>> b3Vzcy56YWltQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): <<<getline<<< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): >>>putline>>> aG90bWFpbGhvdG1haWw=
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): <<<getline<<< 535 Authentication credentials invalid
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): The SMTP server did not accept Auth LOGIN PASSWD value.
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): >>>putline>>> QUIT
2014.07.23 14:07:26 (Wed): <<<getline<<< 221 gmx.com Service closing transmission channel
```

Do you have you any idea about how to resolve the problem?

I am using [Blat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/) to send the emails

Comment: It appears your authentication credentials are not valid based on the error.  What are you using to actually send the emails beause you don't indicate that.

Comment: i'm using blat, and i'm sure that authentication credentials are valid

Comment: The server allows SMTP connections.  What restrictions does it place on those connections?

Comment: honestly i do not know! I know nothing about network

Comment: If you don't know how can we answer this question?  **I suggest you find out.**

Comment: _The SMTP server did not accept Auth PLAIN value_ guessing servers expects SSL/TLS connection

Comment: @user2480100, Freunde I am sure that either your credentials or your SMTP server are **wrong** in absolute terms. How is it that you are logging into a gmx server using a gmail.com username????

Answer (score 4):

I think you can easily get it done through Powershell.

Follow these Steps:

Step 1 - Open CMD (Run as Administrator)
Step 2 - Type Powershell (Hit Enter)
Step 3 - Copy the below code in notepad first

```
$EmailFrom = “Your email Address” $EmailTo = “Recipients email Address”
$Subject = “The subject of your email”
$Body = “This is just a test mail to verify the working of CMD”
$SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“username”, “password”);
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

Step 4 - change Your Email address to sender's email
Step 5 - Change Recipients Email Address
Step 6 - Replace Subject and body text according to your need
Step 7 - Replace "username" and "password" with your credentials.
Step 8 - Copy the above code and paste in windows Powershell.

This will surely work for gmail. For others you may try changing the SMTP server and client details.

Comment: I can not switch to Powershell, because this sends of emails is just a small part of my script, do you another idea ?

Answer (score 2):

As others have guessed, this is because of Gmail requiring TLS/SSL connection and from what I can see Blat does not support that.

I worked around it with [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) which works really well. It sets up a TLS/SSL tunnel (to gmail SMTP in this case) which non-TLS/SSL enabled apps can use to send emails through. I also use it to email (via gmail) from a couple of other apps that don't support TLS/SSL. TBH I don't recall the config but it was pretty straight forward.

You still use your gmail credentials, but substitute your stunnel server (localhost? - I have it set up on it's own Linux server and use it's IP but it's cross platform so I guess it could use localhost on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

It works for me, by using double quotes around variables.

I am using batch script to call powershell Send-MailMessage

> Batch Script:send_email.bat

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -windowstyle hidden -command 'E:\path\send_email.ps1
```

> Pwershell Script send_email.ps1

```
Send-MailMessage -From "noreply@$env:computername" -To '<target_email@example.com>' -Subject 'Blah Blah' -SmtpServer  'smtp.domain.com'  -Attachments 'E:\path\file.log' -BODY "Blah Blah on Host: $env:computername "
```